# Pagination links not showing on arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

My app fetches the covers to each of their Facebook photo albums (I do this with Koala), and I'm trying to paginate the results with will_paginate. I have pagination working on other elements, but it doesn't seem to like working with arrays.

I've gone through the documentation, I've used `require 'will_paginate/array'`, and I can get it to limit the amount of entries per page - I have seven albums, and will_paginate will display the first four with the below code:

```
albums = graph.get_connections("me", "albums")

@albums = albums.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
```

But dropping `<% will_paginate @albums %>` anywhere into the view doesn't seem to affect anything, and certainly doesn't generate the pagination links. Is there something I'm missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<%= %>`  Instead of `<% %>`

i.e

Change

```
<% will_paginate @albums %>
```

To

```
<%= will_paginate @albums %>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I knew it would turn out to be something silly - I'm still getting to grips with Rails :)